# Loop through predict() in R

Tags: r, r-caret

I am trying to loop through a list of 3 methods available in the caret package ("BstLm", "glmnet", "penalized").  Everything is exactly the same in the loop except the method chosen for each loop, so I think this should be an easy loop.

I would like to eventually append each model's output to a list, but before I can get there, I need to understand why the loop below doesn't work.  If you were to remove the loop, and just manually insert the model/method (method = glmnet), the code works perfect.  So something is being lost in the loop.

```
library(caret)
library(glmnet)

#select trainControl
ctrl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5, repeats = 5, verboseIter = TRUE, savePredictions = TRUE)

# method list
methodlist <- c("BstLm", "glmnet", "penalized")  


for(i in methodlist){

#round 1
fit <- caret::train(y = as.vector(y), 
                      x = x, 
                      method = i, 
                      trControl = ctrl,
                      preProc = c("center", "scale"))

output <- predict(fit ,t)
output
}
```

dput of data:

```
x <- 
structure(c(1.400807408, 1.364480432, 1.500560251, 1.26586703, 
1.443177251, 1.408981751, 1.561259129, 1.277240132, 1.491666004, 
1.420852347, 1.630816133, 1.35267138, 1.655465536, 0.814866998, 
0.810722787, 0.808929484, 0.761434594, 0.895402351, 0.848954869, 
0.845575348, 0.747585665, 0.874905836, 0.865513017, 0.975609297, 
0.854114665, 1.074622982, 1.353233718, 1.223561632, 1.371179077, 
1.1329647, 1.448655476, 1.30866331, 1.471799742, 1.180619459, 
1.49988356, 1.33803596, 1.547472083, 1.270202835, 1.690135722, 
0.225475353, 0.228977389, 0.206850776, 0.183182427, 0.25879326, 
0.272921939, 0.250835712, 0.229553218, 0.29439353, 0.301015133, 
0.279187879, 0.254124205, 0.363056704, 1.175400257, 1.136855937, 
1.277755633, 1.146206896, 1.230099913, 1.194888116, 1.329147671, 
1.160423782, 1.285397495, 1.214467169, 1.387038265, 1.237106394, 
1.437157096, 2.049086011, 1.956653266, 2.103276536, 2.068954529, 
2.217281284, 2.090954603, 2.257380717, 2.147282634, 2.286721518, 
2.201965244, 2.448933365, 2.364325727, 2.530556444, 3.449703984, 
3.170076434, 3.494695312, 3.308829513, 3.585369619, 3.284206753, 
3.673954689, 3.378767404, 3.623541875, 3.319163827, 3.757435153, 
3.492152087, 3.913718535, 0.172660414, 0.186281058, 0.166285315, 
0.166955598, 0.207640887, 0.212505958, 0.191188765, 0.18421126, 
0.233655689, 0.238705151, 0.210098712, 0.206674868, 0.286080385, 
0.046424641, 0.045790426, 0.047229766, 0.043122515, 0.046346434, 
0.046747417, 0.048258385, 0.043079032, 0.047261931, 0.04612268, 
0.049793972, 0.044768847, 0.051333103, 0.027276678, 0.027857387, 
0.026956659, 0.026311728, 0.029778712, 0.028433388, 0.027334549, 
0.024817468, 0.027470204, 0.02829008, 0.029842615, 0.027500791, 
0.032395826, 0.041693753, 0.039260192, 0.041295334, 0.036761682, 
0.043537555, 0.04108965, 0.043489385, 0.037844418, 0.044414194, 
0.041268713, 0.04404975, 0.039553215, 0.048715961, 0.00680112, 
0.00686115, 0.006123778, 0.005844483, 0.007480583, 0.008010849, 
0.007215084, 0.006941924, 0.008367775, 0.008769686, 0.007945229, 
0.00765007, 0.010195462, 0.040472736, 0.039892902, 0.042624436, 
0.039853511, 0.040968117, 0.040304279, 0.043277726, 0.039822075, 
0.042129873, 0.040744442, 0.044548313, 0.041214776, 0.046065241, 
0.073739438, 0.071306088, 0.074818233, 0.07529674, 0.076494871, 
0.074540589, 0.077997296, 0.076230605, 0.077762856, 0.07637923, 
0.082370045, 0.081061902, 0.083201049, 0.112694966, 0.106541426, 
0.113274592, 0.110175927, 0.113497979, 0.106964452, 0.115059907, 
0.109669032, 0.112113769, 0.10489425, 0.113459493, 0.108813932, 
0.116833805, 0.005320689, 0.005586605, 0.004958118, 0.00508488, 
0.006116573, 0.006336282, 0.005661865, 0.005716691, 0.006735178, 
0.0069404, 0.006069391, 0.006113098, 0.008048097, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), .Dim = c(13L, 19L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
    "12", "13"), c("c1372", "c5244", "c5640", "c6164", "b1372", 
    "b5244", "b5640", "b6164", "v1372", "v5244", "v5640", "v6164", 
    "bv1372", "bv5244", "bv5640", "bv6164", "s1", "s2", "s3")))

y <- 
structure(c(719.185, 702.629, 764.002, 700.136, 745.584, 709.971, 
772.7, 700.4, 743.2, 710.37, 787.77, 721.41, 808), .Dim = c(13L, 
1L))

t <-
structure(c(1.460053632, 1.0156739, 1.4143937, 0.338644532, 1.330006012, 
2.754840348, 3.691103295, 0.269560001, 0.04574815, 0.030811228, 
0.041912515, 0.009290976, 0.044005394, 0.091986379, 0.111882971, 
0.007611613, 0, 1, 0), .Dim = c(1L, 19L), .Dimnames = list("14", 
    c("c1372", "c5244", "c5640", "c6164", "b1372", "b5244", "b5640", 
    "b6164", "v1372", "v5244", "v5640", "v6164", "bv1372", "bv5244", 
    "bv5640", "bv6164", "s1", "s2", "s3")))
```

Comment: Just simply data from a csv, but all data has been provided in dput.  The issue is the model works with the data as a standalone, but doesn't work with the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
fit    <- list()
output <- list()

for(i in seq_along(methodlist)){
    fit[[i]] <- caret::train(y = as.vector(y), 
                          x = x, 
                          method = methodlist[i], 
                          trControl = ctrl,
                          preProc = c("center", "scale"))
    output[i] <- predict(fit[[i]] ,t)
}
```

Comment: Than you @Dan Y, very helpful! Before I check, can you briefly explain what was wrong with original code?

Comment: I  had no problem running your original code, as in, it didn't error-out or anything.  However, each iteration through the loop of your original code overwrites `fit` and `output`, so only `fit` and `output` from the *last* iteration of the loop would be available to you in the global environment after you run the loop.  My "fix" was just to save each iteration as separate list elements so that they would *all* be available to you after the loop finished.